# Referencing for an unknown source

Tags: coursework

I copied a work from an uploaded copy and the references were incorrect. how do I get the correct reference for the work?

Answer (score 2):

You've asked a vague question. The vague answer is that you search for the proper references and document as much as you can find. If necessary you say "the references in the copy of xxx I uploaded from xxx are incorrect and I have not been able to find correct ones".

If you are at a university your librarian is your friend.

I trust the uploaded copy you are working from is not pirated.